# C# creating own flowchart

Tags: c#, flowchart

In a project, I'll probably have to create an application (.Net / C# 4.0) that will provide a flowchart.

I'm looking for the best way to do this, knowing that it should be really flexible :

- Do I have to do it myself, using .Net framework graphics (WPF, xaml) ?
- Is there a powerful library that I can use, that is specialized in Flowchart design ?
- Is there an open-source project related to that kind of work ?

In any cases I'll need to alter any component the way I want (the way they're linked, how they look, the logic, etc)...

How would you guys handle this ?

Answer (score 3):

If you need a "static" workflow designer you can [look at this project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part4.aspx) on copdeproject and start from it. If you mind to execute the workflow instead, have a look a [this blog post](http://www.felicepollano.com/2011/03/14/WF4ReHostingBindAllTogether.aspx) about rehosting WF4 in your own application. You can customize it by creating your own activities.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use one of the already available controls: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=.net+flowchart&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=. Writing something like this yourself will cost you more than buying a license. Unfortunately, I haven't used any of those myself, so I can't recommend a specific one. Just evaluate them and use the one that fits your needs best.